# Developer instance of SSMS with SSRS for Mac

Tags: sql, azure

I would like to use MS SQL Management Studio and Reporting Services, but I have a Macbook.  Can I run SSMS with SSRS in Azure or AWS?

*Edited to not ask for a recommendation

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a **book, tool, software library, tutorial** or **other off-site resource** are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. See: [On topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SSMS(SSRS) only support Windows now.

I think you can think about using [Azure Data Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/azure-data-studio/what-is?view=sql-server-ver15). Previously released under the preview name SQL Operations Studio, SQL Operations Studio tool can be a good option, it provides enough function like security, linked server and database manager, it is enough to use if you only use it for development.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Leon, I've been trying azure and it's too much for me to figure out.  Exhausting trying to figure out the setup, so I'm giving up.

Comment: @JPizzle You're welcome. we hope it can support MAC in future. Can you please accept(mark) it as answer? Thank you very much.